# Проблема с идентацией return

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

Я написал некоторый код:

```
global n, m, matrix, pathmatrix
def rec(x, y):
 try:
     return pathmatrix[x, y] 
 except:
         if x > 0: 
             left = rec(x - 1, y) 
         else: 
             left = (-1, []) 
if y > 0: 
up = rec(x, y - 1) 
else: 
    up = (-1, []) 
    maxdist = max(left[0], up[0]) + matrix[x][y] 
if left[0] > up[0]: 
    path = pathmatrix[x - 1, y][1].copy() 
    path.append('D') 

else:
    path = pathmatrix[x, y - 1][1].copy()
    path.append('R')
    pathmatrix[x, y] = (maxdist, path)
return pathmatrix[x, y]      

n, m = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
matrix = [[int(i) for i in input().split()] for j in range(n)]
pathmatrix = {(0, 0): (matrix[0][0], [])}
res = rec(n - 1, m - 1) 
print(res[0]) 
print(' '.join(res[1]))
```

Когда я запускаю код, функция `return` либо `outside`, когда я её двигаю, появляется проблема: `unindent does not match any outer indentation level`. Нужна ваша помощь

Comment: уточните вопрос. зачем вы `return` куда-то двигаете? насколько мне известно, `python` табо/пробело-зависимый, и лишний сдвиг может привести к неработе кода

Comment: Я думаю, что прежде чем писать "некоторый код", необходимо ознакомиться хотя бы с основами языка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

чтобы не было ошибок ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
global n, m, matrix, pathmatrix

def rec(x, y):
    try:
        return pathmatrix[x, y]
    except:
        if x > 0:
            left = rec(x - 1, y)
        else:
            left = (-1, [])

        if y > 0:
            up = rec(x, y - 1)
        else:
            up = (-1, [])
            maxdist = max(left[0], up[0]) + matrix[x][y]

        if left[0] > up[0]:
            path = pathmatrix[x - 1, y][1].copy()
            path.append('D')
        else:
            path = pathmatrix[x, y - 1][1].copy()
            path.append('R')
            pathmatrix[x, y] = (maxdist, path)

        return pathmatrix[x, y]


n, m = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
matrix = [[int(i) for i in input().split()] for j in range(n)]
pathmatrix = {(0, 0): (matrix[0][0], [])}
res = rec(n - 1, m - 1)
print(res[0])
print(' '.join(res[1]))
```

в питоне очень важно следить за отступами, которые и определяют/отделяют блоки